# How does IBM Mobile First Platform Encryption algorithm impact to export compliance rule?

Tags: encryption, ibm-mobilefirst

How does IBM Mobile First Platform inbuilt Encryption algorithm impact to export compliance rule?  I am making back-end **HTTPs** call from my application and I am using mobile first platform encrypted JSON store. What should be my answer to export compliance?

Is mobile first platform encryption considered as Non-Exempt?

**ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncrpytion**

Comment: Unfortunately that question is at the intersection of legal and computing and is a poor question for stackoverflow. You will get only opinions, some of which may be wrong, and these will in turn mislead people in the future with a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

JSONStore encrypts the data stored on the device using AES256. 
Using this information, you should determine whether or not it is exempt based on the requirements of the compliance.

You also mentioned use of HTTPS for communication - this is a different aspect of security which is to protect data in transit while JSONStore encryption is protection of data at rest on a device.